# User role are effective only after logout in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, role

I got two forms on a view, when the user submit one of the two, I update his role. I look the database, the change is fine.

Unfortunately the php session is already on, I need logout and then login for get the profil actualized.

I mean I got a button that is displayed only when my user got a certain role, but if I changed the role it still displayed while I don't logout/login.

It's possible to refresh the php session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Symfony's firewall include a build-in functionallity to solve the problem.

Add this line for app/config/security.yml, under the 'security' propriety:

```
security:
    always_authenticate_before_granting: true
```